# Updating SQLite DB from DGV (C#)

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, datagridview

On one form I have a dgv. From another form, I can add an item to the dgv and also place the new item into the SQLite database.

What I'm trying to do is also be able to edit the item from the dgv, and have the edit be saved in the database also.

I have this code for CellEndEdit event:

```
            SetConnection();
            sqlconnection.Open();

            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            this.rowIndex1 = e.RowIndex;
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0]; 

            sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE table1 SET item = @item, quantity = @quantity WHERE id= " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex1].Cells["id"].Value, sqlconnection);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex1].Cells["item1"].Value);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex1].Cells["quantity1"].Value);

            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlconnection.Close();
```

This code works, but only if I load the database to the dgv.

When the program is first opened, the database isn't loaded into the dgv. The problem I run into, is when I add a new item (and its the only item present in the dgv), and I try to edit it (aka. change name.etc.), I get the following error: SQL logic error or missing database
near " ": syntax error

Note: When the dgv is empty and I add a new item, the new item is successfully added to the database table.

Also Note: 'id' is the PRIMARY KEY and AUTOINCREMENTed

Comment: You should parameterize ID too. Don't concatenate it into the string.

Comment: If you mean like so: `sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@item", this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex1].Cells["item1"].Value));` I still run into the same problem...

Comment: I'm saying to parameterize ID. I'm not saying it will fix your problem for sure, but it might. And it will at least be cleaner.

Comment: I don't see how that would solve the problem:/

Comment: You should provide more codes to analyse the problem. Mainly the code u use to set data to dgv, and the setConnection() method etc

Comment: Thats the thing. I want to be able to edit the details of new items, without loading up the database to the dgv. SetConnection is just: `sqlconnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source= C:\Users\John\Desktop\database1.db; Version=3; Compress=True;");`

Comment: You're the one whom i answered for filling dgv right?

Comment: Which line exactly does the error come from? It looks like the one SQL statement included in your question is fine. And you should parameterize the ID like I said before. It'll be cleaner (it's better than concatenating string) and it reduces the risk of an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: You have to describe your situation briefly. You want to edit something from the dgv, and the dgv is empty. How can that be possible. You say that you want to edit new items?

Comment: Just show the code you use to insert new item

Comment: No. When I start the program, the dgv is empty (database isn't loaded into the dgv). I then add an item to the dgv (and it adds successfully to the db). I now have only one item in the dgv (database entries aren't loaded into dgv). I want to be able to edit the new item without loading up the entire database. How do I do that?

Comment: I can defenitely help you if you edit the question and add the code you use for inserting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation you're having here is that when you add a new item to the DGV, you are not providing a value to the ID column. So at the end of the query

```
"UPDATE table1 SET item = @item, quantity = @quantity WHERE id= " + this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.rowIndex1].Cells["id"].Value
```

This will become like **id = .** because the ID column in the DGV is currently empty and is definitely a **Syntax Error**.

It works when you load data because, you are filling up this column. So the solution is to provide value to the ID column properly when you insert a new item.

After inserting an entry to the db, get the Automatically Incremented ID by using a query

```
Select last_insert_rowid();
```

Read the value using reader and apply it to the ID column of the table

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=your_server_name;Database=your_db_name;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Courses", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                {
                    SqlCommandBuilder sqlcmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                    DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet(); // remove this line
                    da.Update(this.ds, "Courses");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```